# Fill down skipping blanks

Tags: powerbi, dax, formula, powerquery

I am trying to use fill down function available in power query to replace black cells with previous values.
Below is the sample of data I am working on;

[image]

The goal is to repeat values in column Status for respective IDs. Using Fill down would be easy except for the coloured instances as there is no value against those IDs and I would want them blank as there is no value for them.

The desired output is as follows;

[image]

Is there is DAX formula which I can use to justify the need?

Truly appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi David,
Many thanks for sharing the solution in detail. Your solution solved my issue.
My learning:
Group by helped to group the data based given column i.e ID
Adding custom column, we applied fill down function on "Status" for respective IDs.
and finally, when table was expanded, fill down was properly applied on Status for each ID.
Please correct me if I am wrong!
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start point:

[image]

Select status column and replace blank with null.

[image]

[image]

Click ID column and then Group By using following options.

[image]

[image]

Add a custom column as follows:

[image]

Remove first two columns.

[image]

Click expand arrows on top right.

[image]

Comment: you can answer twice? who knew

Comment: Lol. I should have updated my answer but one shows just code and one shows lots of screenshots and the editing box always seems to mess things up for me so I thought a second answer would be easier.